# guidance needed on using apache commons math

Tags: java, eclipse, apache

I am trying to utilize the Apache Commons Math (3.5) library in Eclipse IDE. I have downloaded the JAR file and have added the library to my project correctly.

However my problem lies when I actually try using classes from the Apache Commons library. I try to create a new instance of "Descriptive Statistics" class as follows `DescriptiveStatistics stats = new DescriptiveStatistics();`

I am getting an error on that line reading: `DescriptiveStatistics cannot be resolved to a type`. Is there another step I'm missing? I'm very new to using  Apache Commons classes.

Comment: Thanks @aioobe I didn't realize you had to import it beforehand. Thanks everyone, it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be so simple that you haven't imported the `DescriptiveStatistics` class. Put this in the top of your file:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.stat.descriptive.DescriptiveStatistics;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked. However, how did you know to import this? Also, if I were to use other classes in apache commons Math, how would I know exactly what to import?

Comment: I googled for the class name and landed on [the javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/DescriptiveStatistics.html) for that class. At the top of that page the package is stated. If you have the library added to your project, you should also be able to fix the problem by choosing *Source* -> *Organize Imports* (that will import all classes that you're using but forgot to import).